# 1-liner regex to sum up numbers in a txt file

Tags: python, regex

Just started learning python and wonder how does one sum up all the numbers in a txt file with regex and list compression.

I wrote the following but not sure how to avoid adding up numbers from empty lists in the findall search:

```
import re

print (sum([int(num[0]) for num[0] in re.findall('[0-9]+', open('xxx.txt').read().split())]))
```

Comment: Tried the following but doesnt seem to work either:

print (sum([int(num[0]) for len[num]!=0 in re.findall('[0-9]+', open('regex_sum_256911.txt').read().split())]))

Comment: Can there be negative numbers or floating point number?  If yes, you need a more complicated regex pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to split the input data since `re.findall` should work on `fileobj.read()`. And also don't specify the index on the intermediate variable while iterating over the resultant list of `re.findall`.

```
print (sum(int(num) for num in re.findall('[0-9]+', open('xxx.txt').read())))
```

Comment: Sir you are fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

With `\d+` you will not have empty strings. With map you will convert all your strings to integer and then sum them up with sum().

```
print(sum(map(int, re.findall('\d+', open('xxx.txt').read()))))
```

Comment: Accept this answer if it helped you!